# Real Analysis What did I do wrong

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I got my test back and my teacher wont put out the solutions to the test. I want to try and see if I can ask for a better grade on this question but before I can ask a TA I need to understand what I did wrong so I can say what parts I think deserve more points. [Test Question and my Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huyvj.jpg)

Comment: That's hardly legible, alas.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you attempt to transcribe the picture, instead of just linking to it.

Comment: You do not deserve more points. You actually need to use *only* continuity at $x_0$, and the teacher misled you by stating a stronger hypothesis. The whole point is to choose $\epsilon$ correctly and use the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of continuity at $x_0$.

Comment: Things start getting illogical after "since clearly $x_0-2\delta<x_0$".

Comment: 4 out of 10 points, for nothing?!

Comment: 4/10 seems fair to me. Maybe you had the right idea but yours steps are really confusing.

Comment: Nope, not the right idea. The grade was generous.

Comment: How can you be so sure that $f(x_0 - 2 \delta) < f(x_0) $? The argument is certainly less, but you are assuming the function is increasing on that interval here.

Answer (score 1):

You are vastly overcomplicating the problem, so I thought I'd show you a quicker/cleaner approach using nothing but the definition of continuity.

$f$ is continuous, so $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. 
$$|x-x_0|< \delta \space\text{ implies } \space |f(x) - f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$
Namely, this relationship holds if we choose $\epsilon = f(x_0)/2$.

So $\exists \delta_0 > 0$ s.t.
$$x \in (x_0 - \delta_0, x_0 + \delta_0) \space \text{ implies } f(x) \in (\frac {f(x_0)}{2}, \frac{3f(x_0)}{2}) $$
The desired result directly follows.

**Note:**
This is not the largest interval where this happens, but the question only asked for the existence of *some* interval.